# Message function doesn't display its output neither in *ielm* buffer nor in minibuffer

Tags: echo-area, message, ielm

I'm working on ELisp on *ielm* buffer and suddenly messages stop to appear:

```
(defun my-fun ()
  (message "%s" "tom")
   3)
```

`(my-fun)` -> 3, it doesn't display the message

`(message "%s" "tom")` -> "tom" as expression result, but it doesn't display the message, normally it would be "tom" /n "tom" twice.

I checked:

inhibit-message = nil;

message-log-max = 1000;

`(advice--p (advice--symbol-function 'message))` -> nil

The message doesn't appears nor in minibuffer:

M-: `(progn (message "%s" "tom") 3)` -> 3 (#03, #x3, ?/C-c)

How can I recover normal work of my message function?

Comment: "... it doesn't display the message"  - where are you looking? At the *echo area*? In the `*Messages*` buffer? Somewhere else? The echo area might be overwritten quickly because of other things happening, but the `*Messages*` buffer should have everything (although if you add the same message to it multiple times, it doesn't show it multiple times: it shows something like `tom [4 times]`).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking about IELM or about `M-: (my-fun)`? Please clarify.

Comment: To NickD: at the last comand "Mesage"  buffer doesn't appear because the output is too short on two lines. Normally it would have appeared "tom" \n 3

Comment: Both IELM and M-: have the same behavior, they don't display the output of message built in function. I tried with print function and it's ok.

Comment: M-: (my-fun) display only 3 output : 3 (#03, #x3, ?/C-c)

Comment: `C-h e` will raise the \*Messages\* buffer (or you can use any other method of switching to it).  Regardless of whether the buffer is being displayed at the time, your message *will* (should) be logged there.  That's the **primary** (and most reliable) destination for messages.  The message will also be in the echo area for some amount of time, but depending on what *else* needs to be subsequently displayed there, there's no guarantee that a message will *persist* in the echo area (and it might be clobbered so quickly as to never actually be displayed).

Comment: The latter being what's happening when the return value of your function is being displayed in the echo area *after* the message was echoed.

Comment: If you're looking for ways of doing things differently in lisp code, you need to read `C-h i g (elisp)Displaying Messages`

Comment: BTW I can't replicate your assertion that `ielm` and `M-:` behave the same for your `my-fun` example. `C-h k M-:` tells you that it will "Evaluate EXP and **print value in the echo area**." (which is indeed what it does) whereas, for me, `ielm` prints the return value in its buffer, and the `message` is retained in the echo area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151840/discussion-between-mitu-gabriel-and-phils).